# JavaScript: Diferenças entre import e require

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Sei que `import` e `require` são usados em JavaScript para importar funções ou objetos de terceiros. É comum trechos de código como:

```
import Library from 'some-library';
```

ou

```
const Library = require('some-library');
```

Porém, vejo que não há uma padronização quanto ao uso de `import` ou `require`.

Por exemplo: quando vejo um código Node.js usa-se sempre `require`. Em códigos relacionados à ES6 ou TypeScript usa-se quase sempre `import`.

**Minha questão é:** qual a diferença entre essas duas abordagens? Quando devo (ou posso) usar cada uma dessas abordagens?

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Pouca bibliografia a respeito  https://cursos.alura.com.br/forum/topico-require-vs-import-39026

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Essas ferramentas pertencem a gerações diferentes.

O `require` existe só em CommonJS (a maneira que o Node.js criou para importar e exportar modulos dentro de uma aplicação), e o `import` é ES6, ou seja uma nova ferramenta que ambos JavaScript do browser e JavaScript do servidor (Node.js) podem usar.

Para além dessa diferença histórica há diferenças de utilização, onde o `import` é mais flexivel, moderno e poderoso que o `require`.

É importante contudo ter em conta que alguns browsers ainda não suportam ES6, por isso pode ser preciso compilar antes de usar.

O require usa `module.exports`, que é a sintaxe "antiga" (mas ainda válida) para exportar um módulo, e que pode ser o que quisermos, um objeto, uma string, etc.

O `import` usa ambos, ou seja podes usar `module.exports` e `export`, e permite exportar vários pedaços de código mais ou menos como o `module.export` fazia. Uma das vantagens do `import` é que pode importar só partes do que foi exportado:

## Exemplos:

Ficheiro que exporta:

```
// ficheiro A.js

// sintaxe CommonJS
module.exports = {
    foo: function(){ return 'bar';},
    baz: 123
}

// sintaxe ES6
export function foo(){ return 'bar';}
export const baz = 123;

// ou

function foo(){ return 'bar';}
const baz = 123;

export default {foo, baz};
```

Ficheiro que importa:

```js
// ficheiro B.js

// sintaxe CommonJS
const A = require('./A.js');
const foo = A.foo;
const baz = A.baz;

// sintaxe ES6
import * as A from './A.js';
const foo = A.foo;
const baz = A.baz;

// ou somente
import {foo, baz} from './A.js';
```

Quando usas `export default` (sintaxe ES6) isso implica que só exportas uma coisa por ficheiro. Se for um objeto o import pode importar só pedaços, mas se for uma função por exemplo então podes usar somente `import foo from './A.js';` sem precisar de `{}` ou `* as foo`.

Answer (score -2):

Esta tabela mostra as diferenças de uso entre `require` e `import`:

| Versão | Importação | Exportação |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CommonJS | `require` | `module.exports` |
| ES6+ | `import` | `export` |

Além disso,

Você não pode carregar seletivamente apenas as partes necessárias com `require`, mas com `import`, você pode carregar seletivamente apenas as partes necessárias, o que pode economizar memória.

Com `require`, o carregamento é síncrono (passo a passo). Por outro lado, `import` pode ser assíncrono (sem esperar pela importação anterior), portanto, pode ter um desempenho um pouco melhor do que o `require`.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46677972/4072641

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Tudo bem. Confesso que a resposta do Sergio está mais completa que a minha, mas minha intenção foi apenas agregar com um pouco mais de informações. A propósito, se você seguir a fonte de onde tirei a resposta, verá que é simplesmente a resposta mais votada e aceita pelo autor, no site oficial stackoverflow.