# Diferença entre @ e ./ na função import

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Gostaria de saber a diferença entre os códigos abaixo:

```
import module from '@module'
import module from 'module'
```

Recentemente tive um problema onde tive que parar de usar

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
```

e colocar

```
import firebase from '@firebase'
```

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/213910/javascript-diferen%C3%A7as-entre-import-e-require

Comment: A quem interessar, [What is the meaning of the “at” (@) prefix on npm packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36667258/1452488)

Comment: Também pode ser que esse @ esteja sendo usado como um alias, exemplo [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42753045/4056678). Em qual parte dos exemplos está sendo usado `./`?