# Import ou Require qs.stringify dentro de script JavaScript

Tags: javascript, querystring

É possível aplicar um **import** ou um **require** no querystring.stringify para utilizá-lo dentro de um  em javascript puro? Qual a forma ideal para essa implementação abaixo?

Ex:

```
<script>
    var qs = require('qs');

    let data = { email: email, password: password };
    data = qs.stringify(data);
</script>
```

Ou

```
<script>
    import qs from 'qs';

    let data = { email: email, password: password };
    data = qs.stringify(data);
</script>
```

Comment: Pode ajudá-lo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/213938/99718

Comment: Muito obrigado pela indicação desse link!