# Javascript Abstract Classes

Tags: javascript

Como que eu posso ter uma classe abstrata e suas classes extendidas num mesmo arquivo?

exemplo:
em formas.js

```
class default {
  constructor(width){
    this.width = width
  }
  area(){
    return this.width ** 2
  }
}

module.exports = class cubo extends default {
  some unique stuff for cube...
}
```

Como eu posso criar uma referencia do cubo no meu index.js?
Eu já tentei:

```
const formas = require('./formas.js')
const cubo = new Cubo(width)
```

e tentei isso também:

```
const formas = require('./formas.js')
const cubo = new formas.Cubo(width)
```

O que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow **em português**. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, você também pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no [site em inglês do StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Não pode export assim e também qual razão disso, aonde está fazendo isso? falta muito contexto

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [JavaScript: Diferenças entre import e require](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/213910/javascript-diferen%c3%a7as-entre-import-e-require)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu `formas` no arquivo que você importa vai ser igual ao `module.exports` do arquivo que exporta.

Exporte assim:

```
class default {
  constructor(width){
    this.width = width
  }
  area(){
    return this.width ** 2
  }
}

class Cubo extends default {
  some unique stuff for cube...
}

module.exports = Cubo
```

Importe assim:

```
const Cubo = require('./formas.js')
const cubo = new Cubo()
```

Comment: Valeeu amigo, tu é o cara :D
Deu certo