# Como importar o conteúdo de um JSON dentro de um módulo ESM (ECMAScript modules) no Node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, módulo-ecmascript

É comum eu ver em cursos online, artigos e tutoriais pela internet, códigos em Node.js que posuem recuros de importar arquivos JSON locais para dentro do código para serem manipulados, usados, testados, etc... Nestes exemplos, ele usam o CommonJS para fazer a importação do JSON, usando o `require()`. Algo como (por exemplo):

Estrutura de pasta:

```
|
 \_ test.json
|
 \_ index.js
```

Conteúdo do JSON:

```js
{
  "foo": "baz"
}
```

Código Node.js:

```
const json = require('./test.json');

// exibe: { foo: 'baz' }
console.log(json);
```

O problema é que essa metodologia **não funciona quando se usa ESM** (ECMAScript modules). O código abaixo vai retornar um erro:

<sub>Para quem não sabe, em versões recentes do Node.js você pode usar ESM configurando o *package.json* definindo `"type": "module"`.</sub>

```
import json from './test.json';

console.log(json);
```

Erro:

```
node:internal/process/esm_loader:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".json" for /home/cmt-cardeal/<path-irrelevante>/test.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:363:5)
    ....
}
```

Se eu tentar interoperar CommonJS com ESM, ou seja, usar o `require` dentro de um arquivo definido como ESM, eu tenho um outro erro no terminal:

```
file:///home/cmt-cardeal/<path-irrelevante>/index.js:3
const json = require('./test.json');
             ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/home/cmt-cardeal/<path-irrelevante>/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
...
```

Explicado isto, eu queria saber:

- Como importar o conteúdo do JSON dentro de um arquivo definido como ESM **sem usar `FS`** e **sem ter que renomear o arquivo para a extensão `.cjs`**?

---

Minha versão do Node.js ao elaborar esta pergunta: `v16.0.0`

Relembrando: [JavaScript: Diferenças entre import e require](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/213910/javascript-diferen%C3%A7as-entre-import-e-require)

Comment: Eu questionaria essa parte: "_sem usar FS_". Por quê?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A nova sintaxe de ECMAScript Modules (ESM) foi estabilizada em versões recentes do Node.js para substituir o CommonJS, não padronizado pela especificação da linguagem.

Apesar do "objetivo" de ESM e CJS serem os mesmos, existem algumas diferenças. Entre elas, pode-se citar, no caso desta pergunta, o fato de que, até o momento, a sintaxe de ES Modules não suportar a importação de JSON.

Portanto, uma forma ([recomendada pela própria documentação](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_no_json_module_loading) do Node.js) de se importar JSON é utilizar a API de *file system*. Assim:

```
import { readFile } from 'fs/promises';
const json = JSON.parse(await readFile('./test.json', 'utf8'));
```

---

Um outro modo é "recriar" o `require` para uso no contexto de ECMAScript Modules. No entanto, eu questionaria o uso dessa alternativa.

Recriar o `require`, utilizando o referido `createRequire`, parece-me um *overhead* muito grande para uma simples leitura de arquivo e subsequente *parse*. O `require` é extremamente complexo e vai muito além de simples importações de JSON. Não vale a pena.

Só para garantir a completude desta resposta, até daria para fazer assim:

```
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

const json = require('./test.json');
```

Mas insisto em reiterar: o `createRequire` *não* deve ser utilizado para isso, uma vez que é um *overhead* extremamente grande para uma simples leitura de arquivo. Idealmente o `createRequire` deve ser utilizado apenas em casos em que uma *codebase* faz uso tanto de ESM e CJS, sendo necessário criar uma "ponte" para interligá-los. Utilizar `createRequire` para ler JSON é, na maioria dos casos, um absurdo.

---

Futuramente, quando a proposta de [*import assertions*](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-assertions) for estabilizada, suponho que será possível importar JSON com os ES Modules. Até então, é possível utilizar a *flag* [`--experimental-json-modules`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_experimental_json_modules) – não estabilizada, uma vez que é experimental.