# Importar um modulo NodeJS

Tags: node.js, import, puppeteer, export

Um salve a todos!
Tenho como objetivo realizar uma automatização de processos fiscais onde estou estagiando. Estou fazendo essa demanda no VScode usando NodeJS e Puppeteer.

Consegui criar um módulo que abre a pagina de login, abre uma nova aba do browser com a url do normal Captcha (captcha com letras e números distorcidos) e um segundo módulo que resolve o normal captcha através da imagem "já baixada para a pasta dos arquivos (isso com a API do 2 captcha).
Agora preciso executar esse segundo módulo que resolve o captcha, logo após o meu primeiro módulo tirar o print do captcha.

Minha dúvida é de como importar/exportar e em qual momento devo colocar algum comando para que o módulo de resolução do captcha seja executado após ter o print salvo.

Abaixo deixarei o código do meu modulo index.js, o outro módulo de resolver o captcha após ter a imagem na pasta chama normalCaptcha.js:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
require('dotenv').config()
const { toBase64 } = require('request/lib/helpers');

//const SECRET_CNPJ = process.env.SECRET_CNPJ;
//const SECRET_PASSWORD = process.env.SECRET_PASSWORD;


puppeteer.launch({executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe', headless:false, args: ['--start-maximized']}).then(async browser => {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({
        width: 1280,
        height: 800,
        deviceScaleFactor: 1,
        slowMo:10,
      });
      await page.goto('https://notacarioca.rio.gov.br/senhaweb/login.aspx');
      await page.waitForNavigation;

      const page1 = await browser.newPage();
      await page1.setViewport({
        width: 320,
        height: 240,
        deviceScaleFactor: 1,
        slowMo:10,
      });


      await page1.goto('https://notacarioca.rio.gov.br/senhaweb/CaptchaImage.aspx?guid=cb2f6717-8ea3-4688-8333-c132f07f9528&s=1');
      await page1.waitForNavigation;
      await page1.screenshot({path: 'Imagem.jpg'});


      page1.close();

});
```

Bom, procurei algumas explicações no Google de como importar / exportar módulos no NodeJS, mas não consegui entender se preciso importar/exportar todo o arquivo ou se precisa ser apenas alguma função em especifico.

Agradeço qualquer ideia e ajuda!
Boa semana.

Answer (score 1):

Fala Ronyel tudo certo amigo? Os imports servem para que você consiga acessar alguma informação de algum outro arquivo js do seu sistema operacional. Já o export serve para que você disponibilize alguma informação do seu arquivo js para que outro possa acessá-la.
Ou seja, se você não exportar sua função que tira o print da tela ou a variável que armazena o print salvo, você não conseguirá importar essa informação para poder resolver o captcha.

Note que você já está importando o módulo do puppeteer através do require da primeira linha do código que disponibilizou:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
```

Agora você também precisa importar a sua função de print ou a imagem printada da mesma forma que fez com o puppeteer para poder analisar o captcha ;)

Caso você tenha alguma dúvida pode me responder porque também sou novo na comunidade hahah, boa semana!!

A documentação do export em javascript pode ser encontrada no seguinte link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

A documentação do import é a seguinte:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Se tiver dúvidas em relação a diferença entre o import e o require, o pessoal já respondeu através desse tópico:
[JavaScript: Diferenças entre import e require](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/213910/javascript-diferen%C3%A7as-entre-import-e-require)

Comment: Boa tarde Samuel, tudo tranquilo e com você? Cara, esses links me ajudaram bastante. Consegui exportar o modulo de resolução do captcha e importar no modulo principal. Muito obrigado pela atenção, agora é seguir os próximos passos e concluir essa automatização. Tenho muito chão pela frente! Valeuuu

Comment: Bora nessa, que bom que pude ajudar!! Se puder votar no meu comentário é bacana pra quem tiver a mesma dúvida ter a resposta também ;)
Abraços!

Comment: Ainda não tenho reputação para votar :( Mas assim que tiver, pode ter certeza que volto aqui e o faço.